# How to collapse repeating rows due to staggered results in SAS

Tags: sql, join, sas, pivot, left-join

I have a dataset that looks something like this (table2):

```
CUSTOMER   LEGACY_ID  LEGACY_ID_DESC
00001      T121212    COLL_NUM
00001      23232      OTHER_NUM
00001      C22222     ORIG_NUM
00001      45454      OTHER_NUM
00002      U64646     COLL_NUM
00002      C44444     ORIG_NUM
```

I'm trying to join this table to another table by doing the following:

```
CREATE TABLE &SYSUSERID..&SYSUSERID._NEW_TABLE as
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN L.LEGACY_ID_DESC = 'COLL_NUM' THEN L.LEGACY_ID ELSE '.' END AS COLL_NUM,
       CASE WHEN L.LEGACY_ID_DESC ='OTHER_NUM' THEN L.LEGACY_ID ELSE '.' END AS OTHER_NUM,
       CASE WHEN L.LEGACY_ID_DESC = 'ORIG_NUM' THEN L.LEGACY_ID ELSE '.' END AS ORIG_NUM,
       T.CUSTOMER,
       CASE WHEN L.LEGACY_ID_DESC = 'TRMNTN_NUM' THEN L.LEGACY_ID ELSE '.' END AS TRMNTN_NUM,
       T.FIRST_NAME, 
       T.LAST_NAME,
       T.CITY,
       T.STATE
FROM &SYSUSERID..&SYSUSERID._TABLE1 T LEFT JOIN
     &SYSUSERID..&SYSUSERID._TABLE2 L
            ON T.CUSTOMER=L.CUSTOMER;
```

This is the result I get:

```
COLL_NUM   OTHER_NUM   ORIG_NUM   CUSTOMER   TRMNTN_NUM   FIRST_NAME   LAST_NAME   CITY   STATE
t121212    .           .          00001      .            TOM          PETTY       ANY    AL
.          23232       .          00001      .            TOM          PETTY       ANY    AL
.          45454       .          00001      .            TOM          PETTY       ANY    AL
.          .           C22222     00001      .            TOM          PETTY       ANY    AL
.          .           .          00001      .            TOM          PETTY       ANY    AL
U64646     .           .          00002      .            BETTY        WHITE       POM    CT
.          .           C44444     00002      .            BETTY        WHITE       POM    CT
.          .           .          00002      .            BETTY        WHITE       POM    CT
U64646     .           .          00002      .            BETTY        WHITE       FORK   MA
.          .           C44444     00002      .            BETTY        WHITE       FORK   MA
.          .           .          00002      .            BETTY        WHITE       FORK   MA
```

This is the result I want:

```
COLL_NUM   OTHER_NUM   ORIG_NUM   CUSTOMER   TRMNTN_NUM   FIRST_NAME   LAST_NAME   CITY   STATE
t121212    23232       C22222     00001      .            TOM          PETTY       ANY    AL
t121212    45454       C22222     00001      .            TOM          PETTY       ANY    AL
U64646     .           C44444     00002      .            BETTY        WHITE       POM    CT
U64646     .           C44444     00002      .            BETTY        WHITE       FORK   MA
```

I'm drawing a blank on how to accomplish this!

Comment: What database do you use ? Also, show us both tables you are using in your query (_TABLE1 and _TABLE2). Also, explain what do you want to get .

Comment: I'll edit to add that it's going against a Teradata database but the subsets I'm working with have been brought into SAS.  I think you can visually see what table 1 and 2 look like in the result examples above.

Comment: Hi @MandyB , no I do not see.

Comment: Table 1 is shown in the first part of the question.  Table 2 is shown in the join results under "this is the result I get".  Then I show what I want the result to look like under "this is the result I want".

Comment: Reverse, table 2 is shown in the first part and table 1 structure and sample values are in the join result example.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`. Each and every `CASE` expression should be placed within an aggregate function (typically `MAX()`), and other columns go the `GROUP BY` clause.

Aggregation guarantees that only one record will be generated for each tuple of values of columns in the `GROUP BY` clause, while aggregate functions ignore `NULL` values. This technique is called *conditional aggregation*.

```
CREATE TABLE &SYSUSERID..&SYSUSERID._NEW_TABLE as
SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN L.LEGACY_ID_DESC = 'COLL_NUM' THEN L.LEGACY_ID ELSE '.' END) AS COLL_NUM,
    MAX(CASE WHEN L.LEGACY_ID_DESC ='OTHER_NUM' THEN L.LEGACY_ID ELSE '.' END) AS OTHER_NUM,
    MAX(CASE WHEN L.LEGACY_ID_DESC = 'ORIG_NUM' THEN L.LEGACY_ID ELSE '.' END) AS ORIG_NUM,
    T.CUSTOMER,
    MAX(CASE WHEN L.LEGACY_ID_DESC = 'TRMNTN_NUM' THEN L.LEGACY_ID ELSE '.' END) AS TRMNTN_NUM,
    T.FIRST_NAME, 
    T.LAST_NAME,
    T.CITY,
    T.STATE
FROM &SYSUSERID..&SYSUSERID._TABLE1 T 
LEFT JOIN &SYSUSERID..&SYSUSERID._TABLE2 L ON T.CUSTOMER=L.CUSTOMER
GROUP BY 
    T.CUSTOMER,    
    T.FIRST_NAME, 
    T.LAST_NAME,
    T.CITY,
    T.STATE
```

Comment: thanks.  I'll try it.  How does it handle the example for customer 00001 that has multiple "OTHER_NUM" values?

Comment: I'll test when I have a chance but I would guess max function will try to pick only the max value of each relevant column.  So, for the 00001 example, will it drop off one of the "OTHER_NUM" values?